# Training and predicting a Decision Tree over the same dataset

Tags: model-evaluation, confusion-matrix

I wanted to train and predict a Decision Tree over the same dataset because I supposed the metrics will be perfect (overfitting). So I took an imbalanced dataset which I wanted to use as training dataset and testing dataset, and for my surprise I've got this:

```
Confusion Matrix
6012.0  1309.0   
1783.0  16908.0

GM  0.8618945476396955
AUC 0.8629028924095579
TPR 0.8211992897145198
TNR 0.9046064951045958
```

I cannot understand why those values if I've use the same dataset for the learning and for the predicting stages.

Could you please explain this behaviour? Could be something related to the imbalanced situation of the data?

**EDIT:** I've written the dataset is imbalanced, but I've applied a technique to balance it and I'm still getting similar results like the above ones

**EDIT:** The dataset has 104000 instances, the 75% of them belongs to a label class and the rest to the other one, so that means classes are imbalanced.

Comment: How deep is your tree? If it's unpruned it can attain maximum performance if there are no two samples with equal features but differing outcomes.

Comment: Max depth is 5. I'm using the Spark DecisionTree and also I've tried with the imblearn package of python, both with the same max depth = 5.

Comment: I think you'll receive the most help if you could elaborate on your question and clarify the language a bit.  E.g., what does "imbalanced" mean in your context?  Cheers ~

Comment: @rolando2 Thanks for your suggestion. I've added the number of instances and the classes distribution in order to clarify a little bit more.

Comment: What is the shape of your data? And can you share what the resulting decision tree looks like?

Comment: With a max depth of 5, you can't generally expect a perfect fit.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know! I've changed the max depth and the prediction result was better.